# addControl() method for adding the Control in the FormGroup. Anything to add the FormArray to the exisiting FormGroup?

Tags: angular

```
const group = this.fb.group({});
this.fb.array([this.createFormArray(value)]);
createFormArray(value){
    const tableGroup = this.fb.group({});
    value.forEach(control =>tableGroup.addControl(control.name, 
    this.createControl(control)));
    return tableGroup;
}
```

How to add formArray (this.fb.array([this.createFormArray(value)]) to the const group

Comment: The answer is in the question: addControl(). It takes an AbstractControl as argument, and a FormArray is an AbstractControl. Read the api doc: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addControl, https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl

Comment: Thanks, It worked.